# Listar subcategorias de una categoria mediante wp rest api

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-api

Quiero obtener el listado de subcategorias de una categoría, en la doc de WP REST API no encuentro ninguna referencia, tampoco he encontrado nada que pueda valer.

La idea sería poder obtener todas las subcategorias al llamar una categoría, de la misma forma que puedo llamar a todos los post de una determinada categeoría con algo tipo:

https://xxxx.es/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de WP? [Desde la versión 5.7 la API acepta `include_children`](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/02/23/rest-api-changes-in-wordpress-5-7/), cuyo valor es `true` por defecto. Significa que al hacer esto: `https://xxxx.es/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1` obtendrás las sub-categorías de la categoría `1`, **si las tuviera**. ¿Has depurado la respuesta? ¿Qué ves en ella? ¿Esa categoría tiene sub-categorías realmente?

Comment: Buenas, si listo de esa forma obtengo los post de una categoria concreta, pero lo que quiero es listar las sub categorias de una categoria, no los posts.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré la forma para listar las subcategorias en la llamada de la categoria, sería haciendo la llamada a la API con los siguientes parámetros:

https://xxxx.es/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?parent=1

Donde parent sería el ID de la categoría principal